# ajax / processing java applets - How to dynamically add an applet to a page

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, applet, processing

I created a .jar java applet with Processing. I want to be able to dynamically embed the the applet onto my page, but what I'm doing is currently replacing my entire current page with the java applet, rather than appending it in a predefined DOM container. Here's my code:

```
var $projContainer = $('#project_container');

var attributes = {
    codebase:'http://java.sun.com/update/1.6.0/jinstall-6u20-windows-i586.cab',
        code:'tree',
        archive: projFile,
        width: '680', 
        height: '360'
};

var parameters = {archive: projFile, code: 'tree', scriptable: 'true', image: '/images/structure/processing_loading.gid', boxMessage: 'Loading...', boxbgcolor: '#FFFFFF'};
var version = '1.5' ; // JDK version
deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, version); //Want to be able to specify a dom element to deploy to here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up porting to processing.js for this, which has no problems with being loaded via AJAX.

I put a tutorial for that process up here, since people were contacting me about it:

http://mikeheavers.com/index.php/site/code_single/load_processing.js_sketch_with_ajax_on_user_click

Answer (score 1):

> what I'm doing is currently replacing my entire current page with the java applet..

This is a known issue with the `runApplet` function.  One alternative is to:

- Extend `deployJava.js` (by adding it into your page, then writing a new function)
- Add a new function `getApplet` or `getAppletElement` that basically mimics what `runApplet` does, but instead of writing it to the document, appending it to (and returning it as) a `String`.
- Do as you will, with the `String`.

Comment: Thanks - I'm not sure I'm skilled enough to do what you're suggesting above without some sort of tutorial or example code. Is there somewhere you could point me to see this in action?

Comment: This answer is a bit ambiguous, though accurate. For help in implementing this solution, take a look at http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.txt (readable version of `deployJava.js`). It's quite easy to modify `writeAppletTag` into a `getAppletTag` by replacing `document.write` with `return`.